# how to design query layer in CQRS

Tags: java, design-patterns, domain-driven-design, cqrs

i want to do CQRS. where should i put queries? currently i can think of two options:

1) each query should be an independent class that contains just a string? and such object should be passed to simple/stupid repository

in this approach we have potentially thousands of small queries/classes. also we have problems with complex queries (e.g. in oracle we can't have empty `where in (...)` part) so there is no good place to check if that part is empty and simply return empty collection without even touching database

also it's a bit hard to use different queries when working on different databases

2) create 1 method per query in repository object

is it still CQRS? don't we loose the ability to easily select and pass query? or maybe it's not really needed?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be mixing concepts here. [CQRS only states](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html) that there are separate models for query and commands, which is really broad.

For instance, one possible implementation is having two separate generic repositories, one for queries and the other for commands. Query repository implementations may use a database while command repositories implementations may use a different one. Or not.

Passing query classes to your repository versus having your repository implement many different methods is just a matter of organizing your (query) repository, not a command-query segregation concern.

Comment: While the question was tagged with ddd, it seems like the main focus is on the internals of "query".  Could you elaborate on that a little in your answer?  You reference that it's "just a matter of organizing" and I believe that is what the question was originally asking.